# Getting around MASTER_HOST length limit in 'CHANGE MASTER TO...'?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to configure external slave connecting to Aurora RDS. To my delight, I run into a silly problem where the Aurora cluster name -
 assigned by AWS - exceeds permissible MASTER_HOST limit of 60 characters.

*I want to use the cluster name (not IP) since it can be dynamically changed by Route53 on failover.*

Can anyone suggest a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DNS CNAME record in one of your own domains and use the cluster endpoint hostname as the target of the CNAME record.  Then set `MASTER_HOST` to that alternate (shorter) name.

MySQL has no problem with another name in the resolution chain being longer than the somewhat arbitrarily-chosen 60 character hostname limit.

Comment: In addition to solving the problem, you also provided a way to "humanize" the otherwise ugly cluster  endpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved it is I clicked on Modify in AWS/RDS console and shortened the **DB Cluster Identifier** so the resulting cluster endpoint fit in 60 characters.